# I try to install my dependencies but I got a error

Tags: yarnpkg

i tried to install dependencies of my program and I get a error when execute yarn install on linux os

i execute "yarn install or sudo yarn install" a i get the next error:

```
An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/eslint/-/eslint-7.32.0.tgz: connect EACCES 2606:4700::6810:1523:443"
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finnaly was only firewall rule of ubuntu.

```
sudo ufw allow 443
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the strict-ssl on yarn/npm config, and try again

```
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g
```

#### or

```
npm config set "strict-ssl" false -g
```

#### or

```
yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

try these and then tell me if it worked or not and if solved please accept the answer

Comment: I prefer the third solution not a fan of strict-ssl

Comment: i tried  this options and i didnt work

Comment: @DamianTruant, it wouldn't brother because they are for windows device. You are working on Linux distro.